# How can I format this as a RESTful API call?

Tags: javascript, api, curl, request

Im learning to work with APIs. Im trying to make an api call like :

```
curl -X POST https://api.locu.com/v2/venue/search -d '{
  "api_key" : "f165c0e560d0700288c2f70cf6b26e0c2de0348f",
  "fields" : [ "name", "location", "contact" ],
  "venue_queries" : [
    {
      "name" : "bistro central parc"
    }
  ]
}'
```

this works with curl but I am wanting to make the call without cURL. I will be doing this using request from node, right now however I just want to use postman to make the call. I have tried:

```
https://api.locu.com/v2/venue/search?api_key={myAPIKey}&fields=["name","location","contact"]&venue_queries=[{name="bistro%20central%20parc"}]
```

however I get a 405 method not allowed. Im obviously looking at this the wrong way. Is this not the proper way to format the http request?

In javascript would this look like:

```
var request = require('request');
request('https://api.locu.com/v2/venue/search?api_key={myAPIKey}&fields=["name","location","contact"]&venue_queries=[{name="bistro%20central%20parc"}]', function (error, response, body) {
    if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
        console.log(body) // Print the google web page.
     }
})
```

or would there be a better way to structure the options?

Comment: I don't think that will be possible, the original request is sent using a POST method, and there won't be any equivalent GET method if you don't have control over the server. You need the ability to change server behaviour to do that.

Answer (score 2):

You javascript's request is in GET method not post. You can try it as following:

[image: postman]

If postman is the primary method you want, then this should be what you want. If you want to send the request programmatically in `javascript`(or `nodejs`), then you should take care of the request method you've taken.

Comment: Uh-huh, if the owner want to use postman to do it, this is what it is. If a java script request is what the owner want, then your answer should be. However, the author said 'right now however I just want to use postman to make the call'. Wish it can help.

Comment: true true, my bad!

Answer (score 1):

There certainly is, take a look at the docs on the qs object you can pass in:

> qs - object containing querystring values to be appended to the uri

```
 var request = require('request');

 var queryObject = { field1:'test1', field2:'test2' };

 request.get({url: url, qs: queryObject})
   .then(function(response){
     // do stuff   
   })
```